# Getting dn-attributes-failure error after AAD connect upgrade V2.0

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, hybrid

Getting dn-attributes-failure error after AAD connect upgrade V2.0. How to fix the error?

Comment: Hi , Have you referred this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2306/dn-attributes-failure-ad-sync-error.html

Comment: Yes but that didnt help